# How to make my code right and increase variable during every for loop?

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, variables

I have a for loop and variables durIPFS1 durIPFS2 durIPFS3 durIPFS4 durIPFS5. I want to get a common integer value (variable 'sum') of these five variables and increase it in every loop in the same way. Lets say this is results of first loop: durIPFS1=1, durIPFS2=2, durIPFS3=3, durIPFS4=4, durIPFS5=5 then sum is 15. This is the second loop: durIPFS1=2, durIPFS2=2, durIPFS3=3, durIPFS4=4, durIPFS5=5, the sum is 16. And I want my for loop to return sum = 31 as an ultimate value of variable sum. This is my code and my tried solution which do not work.

```
sum=0
#--------------------------
for ((i = 1; i <=$loopsNo; i++))
do
startIPFS1=$(date +%s.%N);
$IPFS_NODE1 "ipfs get 
QmR7GSQM93Cx5eAg6a6yRzNde1FQv7uL6X1o4k7zrJa3LX"
durIPFS1=$(echo "$(date +%s.%N) - $startIPFS1" | bc);
printf "\n Download time of IPFS_NODE1: %s seconds\n" $durIPFS1
sleep $delay

startIPFS2=$(date +%s.%N);
$IPFS_NODE2 "ipfs get 
QmR7GSQM93Cx5eAg6a6yRzNde1FQv7uL6X1o4k7zrJa3LX"
durIPFS2=$(echo "$(date +%s.%N) - $startIPFS2" | bc);
printf "\n Download time of IPFS_NODE2: %s seconds\n" $durIPFS2
sleep $delay

startIPFS3=$(date +%s.%N);
$IPFS_NODE3 "ipfs get 
QmR7GSQM93Cx5eAg6a6yRzNde1FQv7uL6X1o4k7zrJa3LX"
durIPFS3=$(echo "$(date +%s.%N) - $startIPFS3" | bc);
printf "\n Download time of IPFS_NODE3: %s seconds\n" $durIPFS3
sleep $delay

startIPFS4=$(date +%s.%N);
$IPFS_NODE4 "ipfs get 
QmR7GSQM93Cx5eAg6a6yRzNde1FQv7uL6X1o4k7zrJa3LX"
durIPFS4=$(echo "$(date +%s.%N) - $startIPFS4" | bc);
printf "\n Download time of IPFS_NODE4: %s seconds\n" $durIPFS4
sleep $delay

startIPFS5=$(date +%s.%N);
$IPFS_NODE5 "ipfs get 
QmR7GSQM93Cx5eAg6a6yRzNde1FQv7uL6X1o4k7zrJa3LX"
durIPFS5=$(echo "$(date +%s.%N) - $startIPFS5" | bc);
printf "\n Download time of IPFS_NODE5: %s seconds\n" $durIPFS5
#!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
sum=$((sum + $durIPFS1+$durIPFS2+$durIPFS3+$durIPFS4+$durIPFS5))
printf "$sum"
#!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
done
```

Error that I get:

```
downloadTEST.sh: line 55: sum + 
1.556882849+.935912136+.801312520+1.036579153+1.110331068: syntax 
error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is 
".556882849+.935912136+.801312520+1.036579153+1.110331068")
```

Comment: Cannot see any evident flaw. Why do you say it is not working?

Comment: I have added an error of my code. Thank you!

Comment: bash doesn't handle float variables. move to  `sum=$(echo .... | bc)`